# Prompting for Folder selection and saving as a variables

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am very beginner at programming but was able to create a batch file that used the following lines to open a folder chooser and save as variables (`srcfolder` and `destfolder`). My issue with this setup is that we don't get a typical file selection window where we can paste in a value for the folder we want to start at.   Our users are having to click into a folder structure that is 6 or 7 levels deep to pick the folders which the following dialogue makes for a slow process

[image: FolderChooser]

---

```
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose the source folder.',0,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "srcfolder=%%I"

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose the destination folder.',0,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "destfolder=%%I"
```

---

We would like to be able to use a dialogue similar to File - Open in many Microsoft applications but only select the folder and then save it as the two variables that would be accessible to the batch file.

**Just additional context**: We have a command after this which uses the `src` and `dest` variable to convert files, so `convert.exe "srcfolder destfolder"` picks up all files in the `srcfolder` folder and drops the correctly formatted files in the `destfolder` folder. This conversion works just fine from a batch file, just need help with the folder selection dialogue please :)

One additional note, the users that need to run this script are not administrators on the computers.   I found a couple scripts here that work, but require an administrator to login to run.  So the solution can't require elevated privileges.

Comment: You can assign a path to a variable using set /P in a drop and drag fashion. Additionaly, you can open file explorer in a target root directory. This functionality is exampled in [this script](https://pastebin.com/yuDKYvyb) Immediately prior to and within the `:selectFile` routine. - Please note, your question sounds very much like a code request, which is off topic here on StackOverflow. Questions should be focused on specific issues with existing scripts not functioning as expected or intended, not a wishlist of what you want your code to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know a parent folder that's 5 or 6 levels deep, you can set that in [vRootFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-browseforfolder) parameter of the folder selection dialog box:

```
(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose the source folder.',0,'c:\Program Files\').self.path
```

One of the tradeoffs is that your users will not be able to choose a parent folder of the vRootFolder in the dialog box that's displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function when I need a file dialog. You can specify to only show specific files types, as well as which folder to start in.

```bsh
function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) { 
    # Load windows forms without showing anything in the console
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    # Initialize the dialog form
    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.ShowHelp = "true"
    $openFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $openFileDialog.filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    $show = $openFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    If ($show -eq "OK") {
        return $openFileDialog.filename
    }
    else {
        return $null
    }
}
```

Usage:

```bsh
$fileName = Get-Filename -initialDirectory "D:\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which uses [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript), instead of [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for the Browse For Folder dialog box.

```batch-file
0</* :
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "RootAt=C:\Users\Schlief\Desktop\MyTestProject\SubDirectory"
:AskSrc
Set "SrcFolder="
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('""%__APPDIR__%cscript.exe" //E:JScript //NoLogo "%~f0" "source" "%RootAt%" 2>Nul|Find /V """')Do Set "SrcFolder=%%G"
If Not Defined SrcFolder GoTo AskSrc
:AskDest
Set "DestFolder="
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('""%__APPDIR__%cscript.exe" //E:JScript //NoLogo "%~f0" "destination" "%RootAt%" 2>Nul|Find /V """')Do Set "DestFolder=%%G"
If Not Defined DestFolder GoTo AskDest
Echo Source: %SrcFolder%, Destination: %DestFolder% & Pause
Exit /B */0;
var Folder=new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Select your '+WScript.Arguments(0)+' directory',1,WScript.Arguments(1));
try{new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(Folder.Self.Path)};catch(e){};close();
```

To use it, just replace the location you'd like to root the dialog box at, *(line `4`)*, and insert your `convert.exe` command at line `13`, *replacing the demonstration line I've used*.